# getElementsByClassName onclick issue

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Robert Nyman's](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) script to get all elements with same class in document, but it doesn't work with onclick or any other event:

```
var photo = document.getElementsByClassName("photo_class","img",document.getElementById("photo_wrap")); 
photo.onclick = function(){alert("Finaly!");
```

Maybe you know how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, what a genius I was back then. Lovely

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess photo is an array. If that's the case, try that:

```
var photo = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "photo_class","img",document.getElementById("photo_wrap")
);

for (var i=0; i < photo.length; i++) {
    photo[i].onclick = function(){
        alert("Finaly!");
    }
};
```

Comment: @Dima aretias should get all the credit, I only made a minor edit to his post. ;-)

Comment: All the credit to @aretias! It's better late than never.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
photo[0].onclick = function(){alert("Finaly!");};
```

getElementsByClass returns array

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do this, by any chance?

```
var photo = document.querySelector("#photo_wrap img.photo_class");
photo.onclick = function() {alert("Hello!");};
```

Comment: Should be noted that this only selects the _first_ photo.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` takes one parameter, the class name and returns a node list

If you want <img> elements within 'photo_wrap' with class name 'photo_class' to take the same event handler you could do something like this

```
var container = document.getElementById('photo_wrap');
var elements = container.getElementsByTagName('photo_class');
for(var x = 0; x < elements.length; x++) {
    // ignore anything which is not an <img>
    if(elements[x].nodeName != "IMG") {
       continue;
    }

    elements[x].addEventListener("click",function(){

      // do something when element is clicked
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // change element bgcolor to red

    },false);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Using jquery, you can easily target all the elements which have a specific class and assign an onclick event to it as shown below:

```
$(".photo_class").click(function(){
                            alert("Finally!")});
```

If you want to target a specific element which has an id, then you can use the below call:

```
$("#photo_element_id").click(function(){
                            alert("Finally!")});
```